# how can I add an unboxed array to a Haskell record?

Tags: haskell

I want to do write some monte-carlo simulations. Because of the nature of simulation, I'll get much better performance if I use mutable state. I think that unboxed mutable arrays are the way to go. There's a bunch of items I'll want to keep track of, so I've created a record type to hold the state.

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Array.ST

data Board = Board {
          x :: Int
        , y :: Int
        ,board :: STUArray (Int,Int) Int
} deriving Show


b = Board {
         x = 5
        ,y = 5
        ,board = newArray ((1,1),(10,10)) 37 :: STUArray (Int,Int) Int
}

growBoard :: State Board Int
growBoard = do s <- get
               let xo = x s
                   yo = y s in
                       put s{x=xo*2, y=yo*2}
               return (1)

main = print $ runState growBoard b
```

If I leave out the "board" field from the record, everything else works fine. But with it, I get a type error:

```
   `STUArray (Int, Int) Int' is not applied to enough type arguments
    Expected kind `?', but `STUArray (Int, Int) Int' has kind `* -> *'
    In the type `STUArray (Int, Int) Int'
    In the definition of data constructor `Board'
    In the data type declaration for `Board'
```

I've read through the [Array](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays) page, and I can get STUArray examples working. But as soon as I try to add one to my State record, I get the error about the unexpected kind. I'm guessing I need a monad transformer of some kind, but I don't know where to start.

How should I declare an unboxed array inside a record? How should I initialize it? 
I see alot of example of unboxed STArray, but they're mostly program fragments, so I feel like I'm missing context.

Also, where can I learn more about "kinds"? I know kinds are "type types" but the abstract nature of that is making it hard to grasp.

Comment: For learning about kinds:  http://learnyouahaskell.com/   Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`STUArray` is a mutable array, designed to be used internally from within the `ST` monad to implement externally-pure code. Just like `STRef` and all the other structures used in the `ST` monad, `STUArray` takes an additional parameter representing a state thread.

The kind error you're getting is simply telling you missed an argument: at the value level, you might get an error "expected `b` but got `a -> b`" to tell you you missed an argument; at the type level, it looks like "expected `?` but got `* -> *`", where `*` represents a plain, "fully-applied" type (like `Int`). (You can pretend `?` is the same as `*`; it's just there to support unboxed types, which are a GHC-specific implementation detail.)

Basically, you can think of kinds as coming in two shapes:

- `*`, representing a concrete type, like `Int`, `Double`, or `[(Float, String)]`;
- `k -> l`, where `k` and `l` are both kinds, representing a *type constructor*, like `Tree`, `[]`, `IO`, and `STUArray`. Such a type constructor takes a type of kind `k`, and returns a type of kind `l`.

If you want to use `ST` arrays, you'll need to add a type parameter to `Board`:

```
data Board s = Board {
          x :: Int
        , y :: Int
        ,board :: STUArray s (Int,Int) Int
} deriving Show
```

and use `StateT (Board s) (ST s)` as your monad rather than just `State Board`.

However, I don't see any reason to use `ST` or mutable structures in general here, and I would instead suggest using a simple immutable array, and mutating it in the same way as the rest of your state, with the `State` monad:

```
data Board = Board {
          x :: Int
        , y :: Int
        ,board :: UArray (Int,Int) Int
} deriving Show
```

(using [`Data.Array.Unboxed.UArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-Unboxed.html))

This can be "modified" just like any other element of your record, by transforming it with the pure functions from the [immutable array interface](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-IArray.html).

Comment: Ok, that's making sense to me. When you say "modified" do you mean that it will actually be replaced with a copy reflecting the changes? I don't want to incur the cost of lots of copies because there will be many, many changes.

Comment: Yes, in the case of an unboxed array, there'll be a complete copy on every update. This is why arrays aren't as common in Haskell as in other languages; if your board is large, then consider using a `Map` or `HashMap` (from [unordered-containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers)) instead.

Comment: `ST` arrays are generally only used in hand-optimised, performance sensitive code that doesn't really take advantage of Haskell's purely-functional nature or laziness at all. That can be a big win when a certain piece of code absolutely has to go as fat as possible, but isn't the kind of thing you'd want to write a whole program with.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think this will be performance sensitive code, so if I want to use a mutable ST array, despite your undoubtedly well founded advice, I can change the type signature of growBoard like this: growBoard :: StateT (Board s) (ST s) Int. But what about the variable "b = Board{..."? Where does it get the state s in the newArray call?

Comment: You'll have to initialise the array in the `ST` monad: `runST $ do { array <- newArray ((1,1),(10,10)) 37; let b = Board 5 5 array; runStateT growBoard b }`